# восстановление outlook пароля

Tags: windows, office, outlook

Потерялся пароль в заметках от Outlook, не могу теперь войти, а там очень много важных писем с данными клиентов, да и те только. Скажите пожалуйста, это конец или можно как-то обойти защиту? Microsoft Outlook 2010, Microsoft Office 2010, Windows 7.

Comment: Хм.. Не знаю, что за заметки. Речь о самом почтовом аккаунте? Пароль где-нибудь сохранён? Почтовые программы (в том числе сам outlook), браузер? Если да, то можно оттуда достать. Ещё можно попробовать сброс пароля.

Comment: Насколько я помню, заметки Outlook хранятся в почтовом файле - формата pst. Соответственно, защиту потребуется снимать с этого файла. Программ для снятия паролей с почтовых файлов MS Outlook вполне достаточно, у них только один недостаток - они платные.

Comment: https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%8B-58b62e89-6a9b-467b-8865-d5633fcacc3f#ID0EAABAAA=2016,_2013,_2010